# Internal transactions on Rinkeby - Metamask, ICO through wizard.oracles.org

Tags: metamask, rinkeby, internal-transactions

I have tried to play with solidity and smart contracts.

I created "ICO" through wizard.oracles.org on Rinkeby network. Then I tried to send ethereum there from 2nd account, I received tokens on that second account, but I cannot find where Ether went.

There is internal transaction from smart contract to my account through which I created it, but Metamask balance is not changed.

Should I call some function from smart contract? Its standard ERC20
Thanks.

Smart contract: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x7f81fe39b181c4ef88cf30d610760ccad52af2fe

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: How can I transfer raised ETH from ICO from smart contract to my account?

I am not sure if it should be automatic, 
or should I call some function 

and if internal transaction counts as normal transaction with only difference that is executed by smart contract or is it more complicated?

Comment: Does your smart contract have a transfer function that you have access to?

Answer (score 0):

Ether is collected at the wallet address you filled at the step 3 of Token Wizard:

[image]

Take a look the [corresponding FAQ section](https://github.com/poanetwork/token-wizard/wiki/FAQ#9-when-a-user-contributes-to-crowdsale-where-contributed-ether-is-accumulated).

You can check the wallet address from `multisigWallet` property of crowdsale smart-contract using MyCrypto/MEW. You have got ABI of this smart-contract at the Publish stage of Token Wizard.

Btw, you can use [gitter](https://gitter.im/poanetwork/ico-wizard) for all questions about Token Wizard.